# It is possible to see nonce value using cURL?

Tags: caching, browser, proxy, nonce, content-security-policy

I added Google File Picker to my website according to [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview). I ran into issues when using proxy cache. Cached responses produces Content Security Policy (CSP) errors while fetching `https://apis.google.com/js/googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup`. We start with fetching: `https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html`. Response content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<script nonce="qdLPyo649SRoGa6KMrFo5w">
  window['startup'] = function() {
    googleapis.server.init();
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup" async defer nonce="qdLPyo649SRoGa6KMrFo5w"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Later website is making request to: `https://apis.google.com/js/googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup` which fails if cache is used. As far as I understand how CSP works this response should contain CSP header with `nonce` value but my troubleshooting shows that it doesn't have it. Requests that browser does:

```
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.lb.en.L92w_vMR5kE.O%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo-GjmyR8TQVDKPrbqj5UQg7cU3cCA%2Fm%3D__features__' \
  -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'if-modified-since: Fri, 30 Jun 2023 18:58:00 GMT' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: iframe' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-client-data: CJC2yQEIpLbJAQipncoBCEzdygEIlqHLAQiGoMBBCLvIzQEIucrNAQiK080BALzUzQEYj87NAQ==' \
  --compressed
```

Response headers:
[image: proxy.html response headers]:

Response content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<script nonce="0dydr7sqTq3pOrRxZ6JvvQ">
  window['startup'] = function() {
    googleapis.server.init();
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup" async defer nonce="0dydr7sqTq3pOrRxZ6JvvQ"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`proxy.js` request:

```
curl 'https://apis.google.com/js/googleapis.proxy.js?onload=startup' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"' \
  -H 'Referer: https://content.googleapis.com/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  --compressed
```

`proxy.js` response headers:
[image: proxy.js response headers]